# File Level Unique Permission by custom upload form

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom

I have a custom upload form(.aspx page), that allow my DMS admin to upload multiple documents with metadata.

Now I need to add a new field Named **Restrict Access**. On basis of this field, document that is being upload will be accessible to only selected users.

What I am planning to do is, making it a radio button (Yes, No),  If selected Yes than a people picker field will pop-up. User select the selected user to have access on this document.

Now I am stuck that how I can achieve this functionality of giving file level permission to the users from people picker field in this form !!

Any suggestion !